# Retrieve/print each value from each list from each key

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have a dictionary where the values are made of multiple lists. Example:

```
overallorders={1: [['B1', '1'], ['B2', '2'], ['B3', '1']], 2: [['B3', '4'], ['B2', '4']]}
```

How do I retrieve/print only the 1st or 2nd item of each list? For example, I intend to print as per the dictionary above:

```
Order 1
B1 qty 1 price is $4 x 1 = $4
B2 qty 2 price is $2 x 2 = $4
B3 qty 1 price is $10 x 1 = $10

Order 2
B3 qty 4 price is $10 x 4 = $40
B2 qty 4 price is $2 x 4 = $8
```

Currently, my progress is as follows:

```
for key, value in overallorders.items():
                        print('order number ',key)
                        print(value)
```

The output of that is:

```
order number  1
[['B1', '1'], ['B2', '2'], ['B3', '1']]
order number  2
[['B3', '4'], ['B2', '4']]
```

As you can see from the progress, I can only manage to print a whole set of lists per key. Any advice on how to retrieve each value from each list from each key?

Comment: Loop over each element in `value`.

Comment: Where do the prices come from?

Comment: why don't you convert your nested list to dict?

Comment: I downvoted this question for unresponsiveness to clarification questions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not clear to me where "price" comes from to produce your requested output. Additionally, how does your need to print "*only the 1st or 2nd item of each list*" come into play. Given your `overallorders` and ignoring "price", what is the exact output you seek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
for order, things in overallorders.items(): 
     print(f'Order {order}\n') 
     for thing, quantity in things: 
         print(f'{thing} qty {quantity} price is $? x {quantity} = $?')
```

I don't know where the price is supposed to come from so I inserted a `'?'` character.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, it looks like you were correct :-)  Up-voting this as the answer as you were technically in before the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the dictionary to get the list from each order.  Within that loop, you loop through the list.

```
overallorders={1: [['B1', '1'], ['B2', '2'], ['B3', '1']], 2: [['B3', '4'], ['B2', '4']]}

for key in overallorders:
    print("Order {}".format(key))
    for item in overallorders[key]:
        print("{} qty {}".format(item[0], item[1]))
    print() # print a spacer line between orders
```

Results:

```
Order 1
B1 qty 1
B2 qty 2
B3 qty 1
Order 2
B3 qty 4
B2 qty 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where is the source of prices, But you can do this:

```
for k , v in overallorders.items():
    print("\norder{}".format(k))
    i = 0
    for value in v:
        print("{} qty {} price is $4 x 1 = $4".format(v[i][0] , v[i][1]))
        i += 1
```

This code gives me:

```
order1
B1 qty 1 price is $4 x 1 = $4
B2 qty 2 price is $4 x 1 = $4
B3 qty 1 price is $4 x 1 = $4

order2
B3 qty 4 price is $4 x 1 = $4
B2 qty 4 price is $4 x 1 = $4
```